# Export Images to Desktop

Tags: export

I want to export my images to desktop. But I can export process one image, only.

How can I export all images to desktop at a time? I use SharePoint 2013 designer.

Comment: Where are the images stored?

Answer (score 1):

You can always map the list or library as a network drive and then access all the images if you have permissions to access it in SharePoint.

[Create a shortcut to (map) a network drive](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/create-shortcut-map-network-drive#1TC=windows-7)

Navigate to the list or library that you wanna access, copy the URL and remove everything after the name of the list/library.

For example: 'http://server/sites/mysitecollection/libraryName/Forms/Thumbnails.aspx' should be 'http://server/sites/mysitecollection/libraryName'.

Now paste the URL when you map the network drive, and then you should be able to access the list or library as a folder. And you should be able to copy everything in one go.

When you are done you can just disconnect the mapping.